# Blender apply collider to an entire object

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, blender

I am a complete beginner in anything related to 3D. I made a very simple [object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1W2V.png) in Blender, and I would like to export it to use it in Unity.

My question is very simple, I would like to add colliders everywhere so that it fits to the object. Ideally I would just select all and press a magical button called "apply colliders", but I can't seem to find something like that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use a MeshCollider in Unity that will create a collider according to a mesh, it's more expensive than primitive colliders but if it's for testing or small project you're fine

Comment: I have no idea what a mesh is to be honest, but I'll try that, thanks a lot

Comment: A mesh is what you created on Blender, a "3D shape"